# Dbeaver > ER Diagram > how to filter diagram for non empty table

Tags: erd, dbeaver

Context: I am trying to understand and extract data from the database that is associated with a software application. This application has many features and corresponding tables, but only a fraction of them are used. The database is in a Microsoft SQL Server.

Used Dbeaver to create an ER Diagram. But it has too many tables (reflecting dimensions, functionality that we do not use), to the point that it is hard to understand.

Is there a way to filter the resulting ER Diagram to only show tables that are not empty?